# Is there a way to improve my code that generates a txt file with 10^8 lines with the return of the intertools.product function?

Tags: python, python-itertools

I want to create a text file filled with lines that are the result of a permutation with repetition with 10 numbers in 8 possibles positions and I am using the `itertools.product` function because it returns what I am deserving. The problem is the script takes too long and (I am supposing) a lot of resources, basically processor clocking.

I have the following code:

```
from itertools import product

F = open("dic.txt", "w")
for option in product([0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9], repeat=8):
    line = str()
    for number in option:
        line += str(number)
    line += "\n"
    F.write(line)
F.close()
```

It works perfectly if the `repeat` argument is just 5

Edit: `option` are tuples,  that is way I loop again.

Comment: What do you hope to do with all the results?

Comment: You have 10 numbers in 8 positions, which is 100 million rows.  That is going to take a lot of time.  There are easier ways to make that file, and I also wonder what you will do with that file.

Comment: Doesn't this just print the numbers 0-99999999 anyway?

Comment: I know it is going to take a lot of time. I just have a couple of weeks working with Python and just wanna know from someone with more experience if I am doing well. Thanks for commented.

Comment: Doing well at what?

Comment: Writing 100 million rows instead of -- I assume -- a couple of thousands is going to take longer. I see nothing unexpected here.

Comment: Have you considered *not* creating a 100 million line text file with essentially 0 information content? Whatever you're doing with this text file, there's a better way to do it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could iterate over a larger number of lines before doing the write.
Simply keep adding to the same stringe eg. 1000 times before doing the F.write(line). That way you save some overhead time to keep writing to the file againg and again.

Comment: Adding to that string like that will likely go much slower.  Try it.  Extending strings gets slow as the string grows, and writing to a file is buffered anyway.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I already did it and took other advice from a comment  below and it was the easy way to improve de script. The problem was that I tried to write in every cycle. I just made a big string and wrote it at once.

Answer (score 1):

This is tricky to answer, because I think there are easier ways to accomplish your overall goal (which we still don't know).  But your code could be made better like this:

```
from itertools import product

with open("dic.txt", "w") as f:
    for option in product([0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9], repeat=8):
        f.write("{}\n".format("".join(str(o) for o in option)))
```

You can also replace your list of choices with a range:

```
from itertools import product

with open("dic.txt", "w") as f:
    for option in product(range(10), repeat=8):
        f.write("{}\n".format("".join(str(o) for o in option)))
```

Comment: I think you have to replace `option` with `str(option)`

Comment: @Acccumulation: Or for better performance, preconvert when you pass to `product` (which caches internally, and would mean only converting each value once, not millions of times).  Minimal change would be `product(map(str, [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]), repeat=8)`, but frankly, the simplest/fastest code would be `product("0123456789", repeat=8)`, taking advantage of strings already being iterables of their characters.

Comment: `option` is a tuple

Answer (score -1):

Maximum speed option using CPython implementation details: Push *all* the work to C, allow `product` to reuse its result `tuple` by mapping the output so the `tuple` is converted and released before the next one is requested, and convert to using `int`s and raw `bytes`, to avoid repeatedly both converting from `int` to `str` and avoid all encoding overhead:

```
from itertools import product

with open("dic.txt", "wb") as f:
    f.writelines(map(b'%b\n'.__mod__, map(bytes, product(range(b'0'[0], b'9'[0]+1), repeat=8)))
```

Some of these optimizations might be slightly wrong for your use case (e.g. if you're on Windows and want line ending conversions, if your locale isn't ASCII compatible, etc.), but they're all relatively easy to workaround; this is just one of the simplest examples, for ASCII compatible locales where plain newlines are acceptable.

Comment: Man, harsh crowd. If there is something wrong, please let me know. If you just don't like overly bunched up code that's prematurely optimized, let me know too; I prefer to have the feedback.

Answer (score -2):

Try

```
F = open("dic.txt", "w")
F.write('\n'.join([str(option) for option in product([0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9], repeat=8)]))
F.close()
```

Comment: This will just hog all of OP's memory.

Comment: @jwodder MY tests found it to take about one third the time as the other options, so there's some trade-off between memory and time. And if one is concerned about memory, one could do one million rows at a time.